# HTML canvas how to set image on the back so i can draw on top of it

Tags: html5-canvas

I am able to get the image behind the drawing canvas but when i start drawing on the canvas the image dissapear

```
var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
isDrawingMode: true
});
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var background = new Image();
background.src = "images/pic01.jpg";

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you draw images using fabric.

Here is the correct way using `fabric.Image.fromURL`

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { isDrawingMode: true });

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png', function(myImg) {
  canvas.add(myImg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```